# Best way to make ASP.NET MVC Controller await void function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, synchronous

I have an MVC which calls an external model & an external dll to complete the logic, which is then returned and sent to the view. I need the controller to return the view **once** the setcbcbvals function has finished completing the logic in the external dll. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Here is the Controller:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CBC(System.Web.Mvc.FormCollection form, FFAC model)
{
    //recieve values from form
    var email = escapeCharactersspace((form["email"].ToString()));
    var Gender = Convert.ToString(model.UserGender);
    var UserID = escapeCharactersspace((form["username"].ToString()));
    var Neutrophils = escapeCharactersspace(form["Neutrophils"]);
    var Lymphocytes = escapeCharactersspace(form["Lympthocytes"]);
    var Monocytes = escapeCharactersspace(form["Monocytes"]);
    var Eosinophils = escapeCharactersspace(form["Eosinophils"]);
    var Basophils = escapeCharactersspace(form["Basophils"]);
    var Platelets = (escapeCharactersspace(form["Platelets"]));
    var Haematocrit = escapeCharactersspace(form["Haematocrit"]);
    var Haemoglobin = escapeCharactersspace(form["Haemoglobin"]);
    var MCV = escapeCharactersspace(form["MCV"]);
    var MCH = (escapeCharactersspace(form["MCH"]));
    var MCHC = escapeCharactersspace(form["MCHC"]);

    //turn form to array
    decimal[] cbcInputs = { Convert.ToDecimal(Neutrophils), Convert.ToDecimal(Lymphocytes), Convert.ToDecimal(Monocytes), Convert.ToDecimal(Eosinophils), Convert.ToDecimal(Basophils), Convert.ToDecimal(Platelets), Convert.ToDecimal(Haematocrit), Convert.ToDecimal(Haemoglobin), Convert.ToDecimal(MCV), Convert.ToDecimal(MCH), Convert.ToDecimal(MCHC) };

    //create instance of model
    var scfiae = new FIAECBC();

    //create instance of external class library
    var fiae = new FIAEngine();
    //send inputs & model instance to external class library

    fiae.setcbcvals(cbcInputs, UserID, Gender, scfiae);

    //send to get results page
    return View("GetResults", scfiae);
}
```

external class library. Note: I am a newbie so I'm sure my code isn't the prettiest, but I'm just glad it works!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SharedComponents;
using static SharedComponents.FIAECBC;

namespace FIAE
{

    public class FIAEngine
    {
        decimal d_Neutrophils;
        decimal d_Lymphocytes;
        decimal d_Monocytes;
        decimal d_Eosinophils;
        decimal d_Basophils;
        decimal d_Platelets;
        decimal d_Haematocrit;
        decimal d_Haemoglobin;
        decimal d_MCV;
        decimal d_MCH;
        decimal d_MCHC;
        string UserID;
        string Gender;

        string Neutrophils;
        string Lymphocytes;
        string Monocytes;
        string Eosinophils;
        string Basophils;
        string Platelets;
        string Haematocrit;
        string Haemoglobin;
        string MCV;
        string MCH;
        string MCHC;

        string rag_Neutrophils;
        string rag_Lymphocytes;
        string rag_Monocytes;
        string rag_Eosinophils;
        string rag_Basophils;
        string rag_Platelets;
        string rag_Haematocrit;
        string rag_Haemoglobin;
        string rag_MCV;
        string rag_MCH;
        string rag_MCHC;


        public void Setcbcfilevals(FIAECBC cbcmodel)
        {

        }

        public void setcbcvals(decimal[] inputs, string _UserID, string _Gender, FIAECBC cbcmodel)
        {


            d_Neutrophils = inputs[0];
            d_Lymphocytes = inputs[1];
            d_Monocytes = inputs[2];
            d_Eosinophils = inputs[3];
            d_Basophils = inputs[4];
            d_Platelets = inputs[5];
            d_Haematocrit = inputs[6];
            d_Haemoglobin = inputs[7];
            d_MCV = inputs[8];
            d_MCH = inputs[9];
            d_MCHC = inputs[10];
            UserID = _UserID;
            Gender = _Gender;

            Neutrophils = "Neutrophils";
            Lymphocytes = "Lymphocytes";
            Monocytes = "Monocytes";
            Eosinophils = "Eosinophils";
            Basophils = "Basophils";
            Platelets = "Platelets";
            Haematocrit = "Haematocrit";
            Haemoglobin = "Haemoglobin";
            MCV = "MCV";
            MCH = "MCH";
            MCHC = "MCHC";

            rag_Neutrophils = "i";
            rag_Lymphocytes = "i";
            rag_Monocytes = "i";
            rag_Eosinophils = "i";
            rag_Basophils = "i";
            rag_Platelets = "i";
            rag_Haematocrit = "i";
            rag_Haemoglobin = "i";
            rag_MCV = "i";
            rag_MCH = "i";
            rag_MCHC = "i";

            try
            {

                //male calculations
                if (Gender == "Male")
                {
                    rag_Neutrophils = FindMaleRAG(d_Neutrophils, 1);
                    rag_Lymphocytes = FindMaleRAG(d_Lymphocytes, 2);
                    rag_Monocytes = FindMaleRAG(d_Monocytes, 3);
                    rag_Eosinophils = FindMaleRAG(d_Eosinophils, 4);
                    rag_Basophils = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Basophils, 5);
                    rag_Platelets = FindMaleRAG(d_Platelets, 6);
                    rag_Haematocrit = FindMaleRAG(d_Haematocrit, 7);
                    rag_Haemoglobin = FindMaleRAG(d_Haemoglobin, 8);
                    rag_MCV = FindMaleRAG(d_MCV, 9);
                    rag_MCH = FindMaleRAG(d_MCH, 10);
                    rag_MCHC = FindMaleRAG(d_MCHC, 11);

                    //set view model values to the form values

                    cbcmodel.d_Neutrophils = d_Neutrophils;
                    cbcmodel.d_Lymphocytes = d_Lymphocytes;
                    cbcmodel.d_Monocytes = d_Monocytes;
                    cbcmodel.d_Eosinophils = d_Eosinophils;
                    cbcmodel.d_Basophils = d_Basophils;
                    cbcmodel.d_Platelets = d_Platelets;
                    cbcmodel.d_Haematocrit = d_Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.d_Haemoglobin = d_Haemoglobin;
                    cbcmodel.d_MCV = d_MCV;
                    cbcmodel.d_MCH = d_MCH;
                    cbcmodel.d_MCHC = d_MCHC;

                    cbcmodel.Neutrophils = Neutrophils;
                    cbcmodel.Lymphocytes = Lymphocytes;
                    cbcmodel.Monocytes = Monocytes;
                    cbcmodel.Eosinophils = Eosinophils;
                    cbcmodel.Basophils = Basophils;
                    cbcmodel.Platelets = Platelets;
                    cbcmodel.Haematocrit = Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.Haemoglobin = Haemoglobin;
                    cbcmodel.MCV = MCV;
                    cbcmodel.MCH = MCH;
                    cbcmodel.MCHC = MCHC;

                    cbcmodel.rag_Neutrophils = rag_Neutrophils;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Lymphocytes = rag_Lymphocytes;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Monocytes = rag_Monocytes;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Eosinophils = rag_Eosinophils;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Basophils = rag_Basophils;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Platelets = rag_Platelets;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Haematocrit = rag_Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Haemoglobin = rag_Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.rag_MCV = rag_MCV;
                    cbcmodel.rag_MCH = rag_MCH;
                    cbcmodel.rag_MCHC = rag_MCHC;

                    

                }




                else if (Gender == "Female")
                {
                    rag_Neutrophils = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Neutrophils, 1);
                    rag_Lymphocytes = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Lymphocytes, 2);
                    rag_Monocytes = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Monocytes, 3);
                    rag_Eosinophils = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Eosinophils, 4);
                    rag_Basophils = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Basophils, 5);
                    rag_Platelets = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Platelets, 6);
                    rag_Haematocrit = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Haematocrit, 7);
                    rag_Haemoglobin = FindfeMaleRAG(d_Haemoglobin, 8);
                    rag_MCV = FindfeMaleRAG(d_MCV, 9);
                    rag_MCH = FindfeMaleRAG(d_MCH, 10);
                    rag_MCHC = FindfeMaleRAG(d_MCHC, 11);

                    //set view model values to the form values
                    cbcmodel.d_Neutrophils = d_Neutrophils;
                    cbcmodel.d_Lymphocytes = d_Lymphocytes;
                    cbcmodel.d_Monocytes = d_Monocytes;
                    cbcmodel.d_Eosinophils = d_Eosinophils;
                    cbcmodel.d_Basophils = d_Basophils;
                    cbcmodel.d_Platelets = d_Platelets;
                    cbcmodel.d_Haematocrit = d_Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.d_Haemoglobin = d_Haemoglobin;
                    cbcmodel.d_MCV = d_MCV;
                    cbcmodel.d_MCH = d_MCH;
                    cbcmodel.d_MCHC = d_MCHC;

                    cbcmodel.Neutrophils = Neutrophils;
                    cbcmodel.Lymphocytes = Lymphocytes;
                    cbcmodel.Monocytes = Monocytes;
                    cbcmodel.Eosinophils = Eosinophils;
                    cbcmodel.Basophils = Basophils;
                    cbcmodel.Platelets = Platelets;
                    cbcmodel.Haematocrit = Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.Haemoglobin = Haemoglobin;
                    cbcmodel.MCV = MCV;
                    cbcmodel.MCH = MCH;
                    cbcmodel.MCHC = MCHC;

                    cbcmodel.rag_Neutrophils = rag_Neutrophils;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Lymphocytes = rag_Lymphocytes;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Monocytes = rag_Monocytes;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Eosinophils = rag_Eosinophils;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Basophils = rag_Basophils;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Platelets = rag_Platelets;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Haematocrit = rag_Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.rag_Haemoglobin = rag_Haematocrit;
                    cbcmodel.rag_MCV = rag_MCV;
                    cbcmodel.rag_MCH = rag_MCH;
                    cbcmodel.rag_MCHC = rag_MCHC;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
        
            }

        //return inputs;
    }


        public string FindMaleRAG(decimal i, int x)
        {
            String connString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerCon"]);

            //for each row, do this
          
                //find the threshld values
                String thresholdquery = @"select * from dbo.malethreshold where ID = " + x;
                using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(thresholdquery, conn))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                //compare threshold values t posted values from form
                                string composite = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
                                decimal redlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]);
                                decimal greenlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[3]);
                                decimal greenhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[4]);
                                decimal redhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);

                                if (i < redlow)
                                {
                                    // Red low
                                    return ("red");
                                }
                                else if (i > redlow && i < greenlow)
                                {
                                    // Amber Low
                                    return ("orange");
                                }
                                else if (i >= greenlow && i <= greenhigh)
                                {
                                    //green
                                    return ("green");
                                }
                                else if (i > greenhigh && i < redhigh)
                                {
                                    //amber high
                                    return ("orange");
                                }
                                else if (i > redhigh)
                                {
                                    // Redhigh
                                    return ("red");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //sorting error
                                    return ("error in sorting");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            
            return ("sorting error");
        }

        public string FindfeMaleRAG(decimal i, int x)
        {
            String connString = Convert.ToString(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLServerCon"]);

            //for each row, do this

            //find the threshld values
            String thresholdquery = @"select * from dbo.malethreshold where ID = " + x;
            using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(thresholdquery, conn))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            //compare threshold values t posted values from form
                            string composite = Convert.ToString(reader[1]);
                            decimal redlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[2]);
                            decimal greenlow = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[3]);
                            decimal greenhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[4]);
                            decimal redhigh = Convert.ToDecimal(reader[5]);

                            if (i < redlow)
                            {
                                // Red low
                                return ("red");
                            }
                            else if (i > redlow && i < greenlow)
                            {
                                // Amber Low
                                return ("orange");
                            }
                            else if (i >= greenlow && i <= greenhigh)
                            {
                                //green
                                return ("green");
                            }
                            else if (i > greenhigh && i < redhigh)
                            {
                                //amber high
                                return ("orange");
                            }
                            else if (i > redhigh)
                            {
                                // Redhigh
                                return ("red");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                //sorting error
                                return ("error in sorting");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return ("sorting error");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any code is synchronous unless specifically designed otherwise. Why do you think this code is not?

Comment: This should be completely synchoronous. Use the debugger to step through it if you suspect it doesn't. What kind of function is "setcbcvals"?

Comment: "since the logic must be performed and the model needs its values filled" - OK; what code is responsible for that ? is that the `setcbcvals` method? if so: you're already done: that will complete synchronously. If the `setcbcvals` method is paired with some kind of unmanaged async callback API, then it is going to be more complex, but we can't advise on that without a lot more detail and context

Comment: I dont believe it is synchronous because it seems like the view is being returned before the dll completes its logic. In local host I get the correct values returned, however when I try it on my azure app, it returns the values as 0. I thought this was because it takes longer to perform the logic on azure than localhost so the view was getting returned before the logic was complete.

Comment: Maybe I mean that I need the 'return view' line to wait until the setcbcvals function has completed before continuing

Comment: @FreddieKemp well: if `setcbcvals` is P/Invoke it *is* synchronous; that is not in doubt; P/Invoke calls are *always* synchronous, and `setcbcvals` has *already returned*. The question in my mind is: does `setcbcvals` returning mean that the *external dll* has finished? if this starts background work, then you'd need to look at the API to find out *when* it has finished, but: *we can't tell you that* (because it isn't our dll)

Comment: note: if `setcbcvals` is actually managed code, and it returns an "awaitable" (i.e. `Task`, `ValueTask`, etc): *then* it might be async - and you'd just need to add an `await` (and change the signature to be `public async Task<ActionResult> CBC(...)`

Comment: Ok, thanks. So how would I not return the view until the dll has finished its logic?

Comment: You consult the dll documentation to understand how its workflow is designed and what its requirements are on waiting for its competition.

Comment: @FreddieKemp if this is an unmanaged dll that does background work, then there's *usually* some way to register a completion callback; then it is a case of hooking that callback to something like a `TaskCompletionSource`, then just `await` *that*; but: to give specific code, we'd need to see the actual API surface

Comment: There is absolutely nothing asynchronous in *this* code. Please show `class FIAECBC`.